# How to compare beta subgroup with beta overall group?

Tags: categorical-data

My plain regression looks as follows:

tendaystockreturn = alpha + beta * dummy variable that takes a value of 1 in case a director purchases shares

Now I want to test whether a subgroup of directors will have a higher beta. In other words, I want to know whether the beta of a subgroup differs from the beta of the overall group.

The overall director dummy variable has 52 out of 267 obseverations where it takes a value of 1. The subgroup director dummy variable has 17 out of 267 observation where it takes a value of 1.

How should I put this in the regression? Should I make an interaction of both dummy variables or not? Or should I run both regression separately and then compare?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little unclear - do you want to compare the beta for the directors with that for the non-directors? Or a smaller group of directors with the other directors? In this answer, I'm assuming the latter.

You should fit one model, not two. My suggestion would be to include two dummy variables in the model: one, call it $I_{nd}$ is 1 if a non-director and 0 otherwise, and the other, $I_{sg}$, is 1 if in the subgroup of directors and 0 otherwise. Thus, for directors NOT in the subgroup, both dummies are zero. Those directors then become the "reference" group in the model, and the regression coefficients for those indicators will then estimate comparisons between their respective groups and the directors not in the subgroup. And their $t$ statistics give you tests of significance for those comparisons.

PS - I wonder if your model is too simple though, in that perhaps the should be other predictors as well for such things as the type of company. If important contributors to stock returns are not controlled for, the results of your analysis could be very misleading. The statistics are right only if the model explains the important things that are going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your reply!!

Yes, I know the model is simple. In my own model I add several things, however I wanted to describe the question clearly.

The problem is that my data set has some limitations, because I hand collected the data. For this reason, I do not have all data available. It is correct that I want to compare a subgroup of directors with the other directors. However, the answer you proposed is not possible since I do not have a group non-directors.

So to be clear: I have only one group directors and I am able to create a subgroup of this group. My question is how I could compare the betas of the subgroup and the full group (or remaining group).

How would you do it in this case?